# ASP.NET MVC 5 IdentityUsers has Post. How can I assign posts to user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to create something like a blog application. User signs in and can add a post. This post is assigned to him (there is a relation one to many). The post can have comments. I am using scaffold to create an PostsController. It's partially working. It is creating a new post, but it's not assigning it to the signed in user. My problem is I cannot assign this post to the user.
When in previous appication I was creating two models, I could make such a relation. Is it different using IdentityModel? Is there any other way to reference the current logged in User?

I am using following Post model:

**Conference/Conference/Models/Post.cs**

```
namespace Conference.Models
{
    public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Body { get; set; }

        public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Post> Posts { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Here is my **IdentityModels.cs**

```
namespace Conference.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool IsReviewer { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool IsModerator { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Post> Posts { get; set; }


         public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

**Views/Posts/Create.cshtml**

```
using Conference.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
@model Conference.Models.Post

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Post</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Body, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Body, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Body, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m=> m.ApplicationUserId)




        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**PostsController**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Conference.Models;

namespace Conference.Controllers
{
    public class PostsController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: Posts
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Posts.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Posts/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);
            if (post == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(post);
        }

        // GET: Posts/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Posts/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,Body,ApplicationUserId")] Post post)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Posts.Add(post);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(post);
        }

        // GET: Posts/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);
            if (post == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(post);
        }

        // POST: Posts/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,Body,ApplicationUserId")] Post post)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(post).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(post);
        }

        // GET: Posts/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);
            if (post == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(post);
        }

        // POST: Posts/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);
            db.Posts.Remove(post);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code of `PostController` as well. That's where you should set the `ApplicationUserId` to the current logged in user.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

By referencing in  **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;**
you can use

```
string CurrentUser = User.Identity.Name
```

to find which is the current logged in User
Then you can access all the other properties you added in  ApplicationUser

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to create any model properties which you have created in the above mentioned model and make use of User.Identity.Name in the controller level and save the values(Username/Id) to the required table.(Posts table in your scenario)

Answer (score 0):

The property `ApplicationUserId` in `Post` should be a `string`, because that's what the `Id` of  `ApplicationUser` is by default so you should make the following change:

```
public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
```

Now, in your view, you are adding `@Html.HiddenFor(m=> m.ApplicationUserId)` which is a hidden field but users can still actually modify its value if they modify the HTML, so it's best to avoid that. What you should do is remove that and remove the binding for `ApplicationUserId` in the `Create` action result and set the user id of the post after the form is submitted by using `User.Identity.GetUserId();`. To achieve this, you first must add `using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;` as a using directive.

Your `Create` method should look something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,Body")] Post post)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        post.ApplicationUserId = userId;
        db.Posts.Add(post);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(post);
}
```